# Calculating the sum of all k-sized sub-arrays in an array using sliding window algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to calculate the sum of all k-sized sub-arrays in an array using sliding window algorithm. Is that a valid sliding window algorithm? If not, why?

```js
var sumOfSubArrays = function(arr, k) {
    let currentSubArray = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<k; i++) {
        currentSubArray += arr[i];
    }

    let sum = currentSubArray;

    for(let i=0; i<arr.length-k; i++) {
    sum += currentSubArray - arr[i] + arr[i+k];
    currentSubArray = currentSubArray - arr[i] + arr[i+k];
    }

    return sum;
};

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let k = 3;

console.log(sumOfSubArrays(arr, k));
```

Should return 27

Comment: This feels like this would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/? What's the issue you're having with the code?

Comment: There is no issue, it works, but I want to know if what i wrote here is a sliding window algorithm and what is the time and space complexity of this code

Comment: You seem to ask whether the current approach is 'valid'. What do you mean with that if the code does seem to work?

Comment: I mean is this code a sliding window algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analysed your code and it is actually window sliding algorithm, but done in a bit different way than I'm used to. I'd do it by moving the "window" a bit differently and not going from 0 index twice, but from the last visited index.

Difference is on how we move "the tail" - I move it by subtracting "k" and you by adding it.

My way of doing it would be this:

```js
// O(n) solution for finding sum of all k-sized sub-arrays of size k using window sliding algorithm
function sumOfSubArrays(arr, k) {
    let arrayLength = arr.length;
    let sum = 0;
    let finalSum = 0;
    // Find initial sum of first k elements
    for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        finalSum = sum;
    }
    // Iterate the array once and increment the right edge
    for (let i = k; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        // Moving "window" to next element 
        sum += arr[i] - arr[i - k];

        // Add a sum of new sub-array to finalSum;
        finalSum += sum;
    }
    return finalSum;
}


let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let k = 3;

console.log(sumOfSubArrays(arr, k));
```

Comment: Could you explain why is my code iterating through the array twice?

Comment: I updated my answer above.

Comment: I tested it on some other inputs and it seems to be working as well.

Comment: You can also see that in the code that I provided we're not "visiting" the same index twice in the loops. We "visit" every index (or a window) just once and that is the point of window sliding algorithm, to not go back - but to move forward and not revisit. 

Your question was is this window sliding algorithm and I answered it. It is not, because of the way you implemented it. 

It produces right results, but it is not right implementation of window sliding algorithm. 

I hope my code makes it clearer. 

I updated my answer.

Comment: So what's the complexity of my code if i may ask?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I re-analysed your code and it happened that I oversaw that you are doing it right in O(n) complexity as well, but a bit different from the way I'd be doing it. I updated my answer and left my solution to this, so it can be reference to future, but your code is indeed using window sliding algorithm in the right complexity. 

Sorry once again for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the array, as long as the index is lesser than `k` just add the current number to the `total`, and `subTotal`. Afterwards calculate the `newSubTotal` by adding the current number to the last `newSubTotal`, and removing the 1st number used for creating the previous `subTotal`. Add the `newSubTotal` to the `total` to get the new `total`.

```js
const sumOfSubArrays = (arr, k) =>
  arr.reduce(([total, subTotal], n, i) => {
    // calculate the base total and subTotal
    if(i < k) return [total + n, subTotal + n];
    
    // sliding window
    const newSubTotal = subTotal + n - arr[i - k];
    
    return [total + newSubTotal, newSubTotal]
  }, [0, 0])[0];

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const k = 3;

console.log(sumOfSubArrays(arr, k));
```